# Satellizer: login using FB's access_token

Tags: angularjs, facebook, satellizer

I'm implementing a hybrid iOS web and native app. I'm using iOS native FB login capabilities, and sending the access_token from the native app to the web, which uses Satellizer.

The question is: can I avoid the FB permissions dialog and directly use the access_token to sign up the user and recover the JWT from the server, using the normal Satellizer flow?

Answer (score 0):

Permission dialog is a must for every third party social login.

The user need to approve and to know what application he is going to use with that social network and what permissions he will give to that specific application.

Comment: That permission dialog is done by the native iOS SDK, that gives back the access token, not the code that usually Facebook gives and need to be exchanged in the server side for the final token.

Comment: It doesn't matter. In web you also need to accept permission. Usually the social media network like FB gives you a url or something that you need to redirect the user to. The redirected page contains permission and accept options and after user accepts, he is redirected to a return url that you provide (Usually the same domain). In the return url the provider provides you with an access token or something and then you use that token for exchanges and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it doing Satellizer job of sending the access_token and storing it manually:

```
 $http.post('/auth/facebook', {
                    token: receivediOSToken
                }).then(function (response) {
                    $auth.setToken(response.data.token);
                    loginSuccess();
                }, function () {
                   loginError();
                });
```